# How to horizontally center systems on a page?

Tags: lilypond

I have a score in which the systems are broken at specified intervals and I would like for the systems to be centered horizontally on the page.

I have tried the method found [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42332/horizontal-centering-of-staffs-in-lilypond) but I end up with what the image included with this post where it looks as if all of the systems are stacked on one another. I have browsed the mailing list, stack exchange, and other places but can't quite seem to get it. If anyone has any advice, that would be greatly appreciated. I have included the code below (all of the part definitions in the score come from the file includes).

```
\version "2.20.0"

\paper {   #(set-paper-size "ansi a" 'landscape )   #(define fonts
     (set-global-fonts
      #:music "profondo"
      #:brace "profondo"
      ))   oddHeaderMarkup =   \markup   \on-the-fly #not-part-first-page   \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light")   \fill-line {
    \center-column {
      \fromproperty #'header:piece
      \line {
        \fromproperty #'header:instrument
        \on-the-fly #print-page-number-check-first {
          \char ##x2013 \abs-fontsize #8 \smallCaps Pg.
          \abs-fontsize #8 \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string   }}}}   evenHeaderMarkup = \oddHeaderMarkup }

\include "C:/BoyILoveLilyPond/a million dreams/ly/base/notes.ly" \include "C:/BoyILoveLilypond/a million dreams/ly/base/parts.ly"

\header {    dedication = ""   title = \markup \override #'(font-name . "Libre Baskerville Bold") { \abs-fontsize #22 \caps "HS MARCHING BAND" }   subtitle = \markup \small \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin") \medium \concat { \abs-fontsize #8 \smallCaps "THE SHOW MUST GO ON " \abs-fontsize #11 "|" \abs-fontsize #8 " MOVEMENT 2 " \abs-fontsize #11 "|" \abs-fontsize #8 " A MILLION DREAMS" }   subsubtitle = "" %   composer =  \markup \right-column { \concat { \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Thin") \abs-fontsize #6 \smallCaps { "WORDS & MUSIC BY  " } \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light") \abs-fontsize #8 \caps "BENJ PASEK & JUSTIN PAUL" }}  tagline = ""   copyright = ""   poet = ""   meter = ""   piece = \markup { \override #'(font-name . "Libre Franklin Light") \abs-fontsize #8 \smallCaps "A Million Dreams" } } \markup \fill-line { \center-column { \line  { \score {   <<
    \new StaffGroup <<
      \AMillionDreamsSoloMellophoneOneScore
      \AMillionDreamsSoloMellophoneTwoScore
    >>
    \new StaffGroup <<
      \AMillionDreamsFluteOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsFluteTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsClarinetOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsClarinetTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsBassClarinetPart
      \AMillionDreamsAltoSaxOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsAltoSaxTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsTenorSaxPart
    >>
    \new StaffGroup <<
      \AMillionDreamsTrumpetOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsTrumpetTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsMellophonePart
      \AMillionDreamsTromboneOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsTromboneTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsBaritonePart
      \AMillionDreamsTubaPart
    >>
    \new StaffGroup <<
      \AMillionDreamsPianoPart
      \AMillionDreamsVibraphoneOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsVibraphoneTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsMarimbaOnePart
      \AMillionDreamsMarimbaTwoPart
      \AMillionDreamsSnarePart
      \AMillionDreamsTenorsPart
      \AMillionDreamsBassesPart
    >>
    \new Dynamics {
      \startMeasureCount
      s1*55
      \stopMeasureCount
    }
    << 
      \amilliondreamsdrillscorepart
    >>
  >>   \layout {
    indent = #12
    short-indent = .4\cm
    ragged-right = ##t
    \set Score.markFormatter = #format-mark-box-letters
    #(layout-set-staff-size 7)
    \context {
      \Score
      \omit BarNumber
    } %     \context { %       \Staff \RemoveEmptyStaves %     }
    \context {
      \Dynamics
      \consists #Measure_counter_engraver
      \override MeasureCounter.direction = #DOWN
      \override MeasureCounter.font-encoding = #'latin1
      \override MeasureCounter.font-shape = #'italic
      \override MeasureCounter.font-size = #5 }}}}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\markuplist` and `\score-lines` rather than `\markup` and `\score`, which allows for multiple pages. ([Source](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/text-markup-list-commands))

```
\paper {
  line-width = 15\cm
}
\markuplist {
  \score-lines {
    <<
      \new StaffGroup <<
        \new Staff <<
          \relative c' {
            \repeat unfold 128 { g'2 }
          }
        >>
      >>
      \new StaffGroup <<
        \new Staff <<
          \relative c' {
            \clef alto
            \repeat unfold 128 { c2 }
          }
        >>
        \new Staff <<
          \relative c {
            \clef bass
            \repeat unfold 128 { e2 }
          }
        >>
      >>
    >>
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure where you're going with this --- i.e., did you want systems left-aligned until the last system before a break, which would be center-aligned; or did you want all systems center-aligned? --- but in whatever case, this can get you started. Tweaks will most likely be necessary.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I gave this a try and it didn't get it there. I am looking for every system to be in the horizontal center of every page. Some pages have two bars, some have eight, some sixteen. Regardless the number, I am trying to get every system in the center of the page.

Comment: @twpP5W86 - Is there 1 system per page?